# How do I display the current "session" name or "sockname" of a screen session in the status bar?

Tags: gnu-screen

I run multiple screen sessions each created with 'screen -S ***name***' and I would like to be able to display in the status bar the ***name*** I used to create the current screen session.

However,  I cannot seem to accomplish this.  Any ideas?

Comment: See this [Super User question](http://superuser.com/questions/212392/how-to-include-screens-session-name-in-hardstatus). Also [here](http://old.nabble.com/Re:-Session-name-in-status-line-p22456825.html).

Answer (score 25, accepted):

`screen` has two status bars, the caption bar and the hardstatus bar, both of which use the string escapes specified in the "STRING ESCAPES" section of [man screen](http://www.slac.stanford.edu/comp/unix/package/epics/extensions/iocConsole/screen.1.html).  Unfortunately, there is no escape that directly refers to the session name.

However, there is a hack that will allow you to do this.

`screen` passes the session name to the shell using the `$STY` variable.  When the shell attempt to set the window title (using [one of these methods](http://www.faqs.org/docs/Linux-mini/Xterm-Title.html)) `screen` captures that attempt, and stores it in something it confusingly calls "the window hardstatus," which does have an escape that you can use: `%h`.

So if you have either the caption or hardstatus bar set to include `%h` and have the shell attempt to set the window title to `$STY`, then the `%h` will be replaced with the session name when the bar is displayed.

Comment: Very close... Works great for the initial session however, once I am inside a screen session if I ssh to another host STY will no longer be set.  Is there anyway to preserve that information or perhaps make screen only read the value once at the start of the session?

Comment: @Neg_EV: Well, according to `man ssh`'s ENVIRONMENT section, if the sshd of the remote host allows it (default is not), you can set environment vars (like `STY`) in your local `.ssh/environment` file (so in your local `.bashrc`, just `cat STY=$STY > .ssh/environment`) and when you ssh to the remote machine that will set the appropriate environment vars.

Comment: @Neg_EV: If you don't want to (or can't) change the remote's `sshd` settings, then you could have your local `.bashrc` dump the STY value to a file, alias ssh to first scp that file to the remote host, and have your remote `.bashrc` source that file if STY is not set (that way the same .bashrc can be used remotely and locally).

Comment: I added `alias screen='screen -s -/bin/bash'` and `export PS1='$STY> '` in my .bash_profile, so wtih the _alias_, screen executes my .bash_profile in each session and with the _export_ I can see which session I'm working with.

Answer (score 49):

The easiest way to display the sessionname is

```
  C-a : 
  sessionname
```

(without specifying a name after `sessionname`)

See the "CUSTOMIZATION" section in [man screen](http://www.slac.stanford.edu/comp/unix/package/epics/extensions/iocConsole/screen.1.html)

Comment: Could you clarify this a bit? Is this a standalone command or parameters?

Comment: Type the following three keystrokes / commands one after the other:
`Ctrl-A` then `:` then `sessionname` (Ctrl-A should be substituted with whatever you have set for the screen control keystroke, if you have changed it from the default of Ctrl-A.) 
You will then see output similar to:
`This session is named '31438.Perlrocks'`.

Comment: Neat! Is there a way to get this in a script running within `screen`?

Answer (score 16):

In current versions of `screen`, there is a flag `%S` for the hardstatus line.

MWE (.screenrc):

```
hardstatus on
hardstatus alwayslastline
hardstatus string "%S"
```

This displays the session name *without* the ID (like `${STY#*.}`).

(Same answer to other questions [here](https://superuser.com/a/954751/260809) and [here](https://superuser.com/a/954755/260809) for completeness).

Answer (score 3):

paraphrased from https://superuser.com/a/212520/151988, put this into your ~/.screenrc;

```
screen 
screen $SHELL -c 'screen -X caption always "$STY"'
```

Answer (score 2):

Super User has an answer to this that does not require `$STY`, instead using the `backtick` screen config command and `screen -ls`: https://superuser.com/a/212520

Answer (score 1):

If nothing else works (as for me), as a workaround you can create a window with number 0 and set title to your screen name:

```
screen -S myscreen
C^a :title "myscreen"
```

Answer (score 0):

As max_cantor says in the [SuperUser Answer](https://superuser.com/questions/121819/how-do-i-display-the-current-session-name-or-sockname-of-a-screen-session-in), an escape character for the session name should be added to version 4.1.0. [It looks like](http://savannah.gnu.org/bugs/index.php?23738) the escape character function was added with a relatively small patch back in 2008. So if you're feeling brave, you can git yourself a copy of the development version 4.1.0 and try it out.

I'll try this with the development version when I get a chance.

Answer (score 0):

"screen -X sessionname"
i'm using ssh,i thought this is a straight answer ,
sessionname will show at the screen bottom

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).