# How can I get currently attached screen session name?

Tags: linux, bash, gnu-screen

I'm writing a script which needs the name of the currently attached screen session's name if there's any.

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2479683/how-do-i-display-the-current-session-name-or-sockname-of-a-screen-session-in

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You might want to check answers here: [How do I display the current "session" name or "sockname" of a screen session in the status bar?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2479683/how-do-i-display-the-current-session-name-or-sockname-of-a-screen-session-in)

In short the $STY environment variable is what you are looking for.

Comment: The session name without ID can be obtained by `${STY#*.}`.