# How to tell from the terminal that you are at base screen?

Tags: ubuntu, terminal, ubuntu-14.04

In ubuntu terminal, you can run a command called `screen` which detaches you to another screen.

I was wondering let's say one fellow runs that command and then leaves. When I come back to the server (we are using headless server edition of Ubuntu), how do I know I am at the detached screen?

Or rather how do I know I am at the base screen?

If I try my luck and press `ctrl+a, d` and then successfully detached and go to the base screen, and then I type `screen -r` and it shows a list of detached screens, how do I know which detached screens did I come out from?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before detaching, the environment variable `$STY` holds the name of the session that you are considering detaching from:

```
echo $STY
```

After you have detached, you will not have that environment variable to consult.  But while you are running screen, you can check that.  Or you can ask `screen` what windows are active, e.g.,

<kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>`A`</kbd> <kbd>`w`</kbd>

Further reading:

- [How do I display the current “session” name or “sockname” of a screen session in the status bar?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2479683/how-do-i-display-the-current-session-name-or-sockname-of-a-screen-session-in)

Comment: thanks. i got the echo $STY working but not the ctrl A W thing